# Cannot insert the value NULL into column (SQL-Server)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, null

I have created a stored procedure to input data into the database. The Data is input from asp:textboxes then parsed to a class and method an a .cs file. However when running I am given the following error.
*Cannot insert the value NULL into column*

**add_question.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Devworks;

namespace OSQARv0._1
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        OscarSQL b;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string QuestionnaireName = (string)Session["QuestionnaireName"];
            int QuestionnaireID = (int)Session["QuestionnaireID"];
            ReturnQnrName.Text = QuestionnaireName + "   (ID: " + QuestionnaireID.ToString() + ")";          
        }

        protected void FinishQnrButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            b = new OscarSQL();
            int testRetn = b.InsertQuestions(QuestionName.Text, Int32.Parse(QuestnType.SelectedValue), Int32.Parse(QuestionnaireID.Text));
            int QuestionID = (int)Session["QuestionID"];
            testlabel.Text = QuestionID.ToString();        

        } // End NewQNRButton_Click

    } // End WebForm2

} // End new_questionnaire
```

**OscarSQL.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Devworks
{
    public class OscarSQL
    {
        private string _productConnectionString;
        private SqlConnection _productConn;

        public OscarSQL()
        {
            _productConn = new SqlConnection();
            _productConnectionString += "data source=mssql.database.co.uk; Initial Catalog=devworks_oscar;User ID=username;Password=password";
            _productConn.ConnectionString = _productConnectionString;
        }       

        public int InsertQuestions(string QuestionName, int QuestionType, int QuestionnaireID) 
        {
            int retnVal = 0;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("NewQuestion", _productConn);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUESTIONNAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUESTIONTYPE", SqlDbType.Int));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUESTID", SqlDbType.Int));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@QUESTION_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "QUESTION_ID");
            myCommand.Parameters["@QUESTION_ID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            myCommand.Parameters[0].Value = QuestionName;
            myCommand.Parameters[1].Value = QuestionType;
            myCommand.Parameters[2].Value = QuestionnaireID;
            _productConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            retnVal = (int)myCommand.Parameters["@QUESTION_ID"].Value;
            _productConn.Close();
            return retnVal;
        }

        private void insert(SqlCommand myCommand)
        {
            _productConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _productConn.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

**Stored Prodcedure**

```
USE [devworks_oscar]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [hgomez].[NewQuestion]    Script Date: 10/27/2011 17:10:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [hgomez].[NewQuestion]
    (
    @QUESTIONNAME nvarchar(50),
    @QUESTIONTYPE int,
    @QUESTID int,
    @QUESTION_ID int OUTPUT
    )

AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    INSERT INTO [Questions] (QuestionText, QuestionType, QuestionnaireID) VALUES (@QUESTIONNAME, @QUESTIONTYPE, @QUESTID)
    SET @QUESTION_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    RETURN
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many columns in the table (more than the 4 you mention)? What does the rest of the error say (it tells you what column)? Have you breakpointed InsertQuestions and examined the parameter collection?

Comment: What is the schema of the table `Questions`? Most likely, the column into which you are trying to insert a null value is defined as `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not marked one of these columns as "Allow Nulls". Hence you are getting the above error. Check if the value you are inserting in any of "QuestionText", "QuestionType" or "QuestionnaireID" is null and the column is not marked "Allow null".

It could also be some other column in that same table which is not marked as "Allow Null" and you are not inserting any value into it and hence by default it is trying to insert null.

Comment: This isn't quite an answer: the 2 comments above cover this already. There are other options too as these note.

Comment: @gbn - This most cerainly is the solution to Rupert's question.

Comment: @Ramhound: This question was edited BTW within the 5 min grace period to mention other columns, otherwise I wouldn't have commented...

Comment: @gbn - Sorry for the confusion. Yes. first time when I posted my answer I did not consider the option of other columns. Later I thought of that usecase and edited my answer. Also I must admit that after I edited my answer, I read your comment on OP's question stating on similar lines which was way before my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the exact error message is "Cannot insert the value NULL into column" and you do not know which column is null. To find out which column is attempted to be inserted as null, First create a table for catching your error:

```
CREATE TABLE Errors (QuestionName NVARCHAR(50), QuestionType INT, QuestId INT, ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000), ErrorTime datetime default getdate())
```

Next, add Try/Catch to stored procedure:

```
BEGIN TRY
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    INSERT INTO [Questions] (QuestionText, QuestionType, QuestionnaireID) VALUES (@QUESTIONNAME, @QUESTIONTYPE, @QUESTID)
    SET @QUESTION_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    RETURN
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
   INSERT Errors (QuestionName,QuestionType, QuestId, ErrorMessage)
      SELECT @QUESTIONNAME, @QUESTIONTYPE,@QUESTID, ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH
```

From now on, errors from this stored procedure will be logged to the Errors table. The NULL value should surface here for further research.

Answer (score 0):

Run Profiler. You are sending in a value of Null for some column that is required to have a a value. At any rate you want to see the SQl that is being generated to see what is casuing the problem.